# tensorflow , what does server.join() exactly do?

Tags: tensorflow

[here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/tools/dist_test/python/mnist_replica.py#L122) shows that `server` is the parameter server.

But [here](https://github.com/CheHsuan/TensorFlowAssignment/blob/master/MapReduce/create_worker.py#L12) shows that `server` is the worker.

It makes me so confused.

Comment: "parameter server" and "worker" are arbitrary names -- every worker implements the same interface

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov the worker that you say means machine or process, right?

Comment: `server.join` causes Python process to wait forever. If Python process quits, the server will also quit. An alternative you can do `time.sleep(10000)` instead of `server.join`, or `dequeue` as in here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4713#issuecomment-269499287